# Lookup field value through query is gibberish?

Tags: visualforce, soql, lookup, query

I have a custom object (Team_Assignments__c) with a lookup relation (Team_Member__c) that references the User object. Team_Member__c should be the name of a user. However, my SOQL query for the Team_Member_c returns gibberish (ex: 0051a000000bSMsAAM). I was wondering why this is and how I could fix this?

VF Page:

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!team}" var="user">
            <apex:column >                 
                <apex:outputText value="{!user.Team_Member__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

SOQL Statement:

```
Select Id, Name, Team_Member__c 
From Team_Assignment__c]
```

Comment: Team_Member__c  is a lookup field and will store Id of the user linked not name.

Answer (score 4):

Replacing:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!user.Team_Member__c}"/>
```

with:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!user.Team_Member__c}"/>
```

will render the names of the objects that are referenced and also links to those objects without the query needing changing. The `apex:inputField` and `apex:outputField` components embody common platform patterns (such as this one) and so are often best to try first.

Comment: I thought that too but I experimented through the UI and still got just the Id still.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I recollect getting the ID value in the past but at least in the simple apex:pageBlockTable test code I tried today it worked OK. API version dependent maybe?

Comment: Ah didn't try it in a `pageBlockTable`. It doesn't work if you just dump the `outputField` on the page.

Comment: I guess I should do some more testing on where this works and where it doesn't.

Comment: @AdrianLarson The good thing is you are aware of both patterns so if apex:outputField doesn't work you have the apex:outputLink pattern at your fingertips.

Answer (score 2):

It's not gibberish, it's an `Id`, which is the type of data Salesforce stores for all `Lookup` or `Master Detail` relationships. If you want a linked name, you will need something more like the below. I would change the `var` to `assignment` to be less confusing.

You can actually just switch from `outputText` to `outputField` because you are using a reference `Id`. But if you are doing this using a record's own Id, you may need to construct the linked name yourself, which would look like:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!$Action.User.View, user.Id}">
    {!user.Name}
</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: -1 Sorry, Adrian, but you *never* need to use that awful construct if you bind to a lookup field directly. See this code: `public class oneaccount {
    public Contact getContact() {
        return [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId != NULL LIMIT 1];
    }
}` Page: `<apex:page controller="oneaccount">
    <apex:outputField value="{!contact.accountid}" />
</apex:page>`.

Comment: I guess maybe it's just when you're using `Id`, which is what I tested and why I changed my initial answer away from that.

Comment: Not saying I disagree with the -1 (should have just left my original answer) but it's not *that* horrific, it's only one tag with one inner text element.

Comment: My primary problem with this answer, the reason for -1, is you state something that's absolutely false (that you can use outputField *because* you're in a pageBlockTable). You can, in fact, use apex:outputField *anywhere* that you're using a real lookup field, and have it render correctly. In fact, I'd like proof that there's a place where it *doesn't* work, because I've never seen it fail.

Comment: `<apex:page standardController="Account"><apex:outputField value="{!Account.Id}" /></apex:page>`

Comment: `Id` is an `Id` type, *not* a lookup field, so the behavior would be expected that you'd see an Id. And, of course, the solution would be to use {!Account.Name} instead (which you still wouldn't have to query for in this case).

Comment: @AdrianLarson - That is a different use case right? Account.id is not a lookup field.

Answer (score 0):

`Team_Member__c` will only return a reference id to that record. To access the fields such as `Name` properly you will want to display `Team_Member__r.Name`.

This will delve into the record itself to return a value and not just the id on the `Team_Assignment__c` object